# JSON string not deserializing

Tags: c#, json, deserialization, prtg

I have a problem with deserializing this JSON data due to duplicate property name `value` and `value_raw`.

I have attempted to use a List based object to deserialize the values but this only results in the last value being stored in the object. Apart from this, the object resolves correctly.

**JSON string:**

```
{
    "prtg-version":"9.2.0.2236",
    "treesize":576,
    "values":
        [{
            "datetime":"29/09/2012 09:45:00 - 09:50:00",
            "datetime_raw":41181.3680555556,
            "value":"49 %",
            "value_raw":48.5000,
            "value":"0 %",
            "value_raw":0.0000,
            "coverage":"100 %",
            "coverage_raw":"0000010000"
        }]
}
```

Please note - the JSON string is what i get back from PRTG, so unfortunately i have to work with it in that format :(

Comment: Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877526/json-net-newtonsoft-json-two-properties-with-same-name) can help you

Comment: How you define you *List based object*?

Comment: Not sure that's the case here, "value" & "value_raw" cannot be seen as a duplicate property name, unless we are missing information. Can you provide a piece of example code of what you are doing / trying to do? as this is valid json it should deserialize just fine.

Comment: Well, PRTG's XML is not really XML as it ignores case, and JSON also isn't real JSON. The JSON specification (RFC) also says: "*When the names within an object are not
unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.*"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not deserialize that as the string you provided is NOT a valid JSON. By RFC, all attribute names inside one objects should be unique. The only reasonable way to tackle that - rewrite the part of code where this string comes from.

Comment: Actually, the RFC allows such things, but recommends against them. "The names within an object SHOULD be unique." That said, I don't think I've ever seen a) this used in practice and b) a JSON library that handled it other than giving you one value (chosen randomly) back. This is likely the OP's problem.

Comment: Further down the RFC states: "*When the names within an object are not unique, the behavior of software that receives such an object is unpredictable.*" - So you could write your own parser that converts the object's elements in to an array (instead of dictionary), or a specific parser could convert the value of `value` into an array containing the individual values. But obviously (as it could be represented in JSON correctly, too) the software creating the JSON should be fixed or discarded.

Answer (score 0):

can you first serialise the

```
            "datetime":"29/09/2012 09:45:00 - 09:50:00",
            "datetime_raw":41181.3680555556,
            "value":"49 %",
            "value_raw":48.5000,
            "value":"0 %",
            "value_raw":0.0000,
            "coverage":"100 %",
            "coverage_raw":"0000010000"
```

into a List of string and then do further process after?

Answer (score -1):

```
"datetime"    :"29/09/2012 09:45:00 - 09:50:00",
"datetime_raw":41181.3680555556,
"value"       :["49 %","0 %"]
"value_raw"   :[48.5000,0.0000]            
"coverage"    :"100 %",
"coverage_raw":"0000010000"
```

change the `value` and `value_raw` as shown above