# Json.net catching duplicates and throwing an error

Tags: c#, json, json.net

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Json.NET (Newtonsoft.Json) - Two 'properties' with same name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3877526/json-net-newtonsoft-json-two-properties-with-same-name)

I'm using JSON.NET to deserialize a JSON file into a Dictionary.  Now what I'd like to do is have the following line:

```
JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<IDictionary<string, object>>(text);
```

throw an exception if there are duplicate entries in the JSON like this:

```
{
    "ExampleText": "Example 1",
    "ExampleText": "Example 2",
    "ExampleText": "Example 3",
}
```

The standard JSON.NET behavior is to simply replace the "ExampleText" entry with whichever entry is last in the JSON. Is it possible to have the exception thrown instead?

Comment: It's not a duplicate.  He wanted to support deserialization even though he had multiple entries with the same key.  What I want is instead of just a replacement of the single TBox entry, I want an exception to be thrown telling me there are duplicate entries for the same key.

Comment: I actually found a way to do what I wanted but I had to use JsonTextReader to parse each token myself.  It feels a little dirty but it allows me to insure that an exception gets thrown in the case of a duplicate entry.

Comment: This isn't a duplicate at all. This is the answer: https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_Linq_DuplicatePropertyNameHandling.htm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**--EDIT--**

You dont need to deserialize to `IDictionary<string, object>`. `JObject` already implements `IDictionary<string, JToken>`

```
var obj = (JObject)JsonConvert.DeserializeObject(json); //will throw exception for dublicates.
var str = (string)obj["ExampleText"];
```

Comment: This won't throw an exception in the case of a duplicate entry.

Comment: @shaqua471 Is this a question? If yes, No.

Comment: That was the whole point of my question.  I want an easy way to have an exception thrown when I deserialize and duplicate entries exist.

Comment: Just tried it: it doesn't break.

Comment: it depends on nuget version. Version 6 throws. Version 9+ does not.

Answer (score 0):

If you look to IDictionary in msdn

> "Each association must have a unique key"

Your problem in duplicated keys. I think you should use another collection.

Try this

```
class MyValue
{
  public string Key {get; set;}
  public string Value {get; set;}
}

JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<MyValue>>(text);
```

Comment: Have you tried to deserialize the json in question to `List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>` ?

Comment: You can't deserialize into .NET List.  You'll get this error:
  Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"})   into type 'System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Collections.Generic.KeyValuePair`2[System.String,System.String]]'